# Programmatically set item selection in showOpenDialogSync

Tags: dialog, electron

I am using Electron's showOpenDialogSync successfully, but I have a minor issue. I want users to be able to change the root directory for, say, a library from a set of libraries:

```
usr/project/library1/
usr/project/library2/
  subdir1/
  subdir2/
  subdir3/
usr/project/library3/
```

Now the issue is, when I use the `showOpenDialogSync` dialog and pass it `usr/project/library2/` as the default, it shows all the subdirectories. I would rather it show the dialog for `usr/project` with `library2` highlighted, so I can quickly switch between libraries, without having to hit the back-button to select a different library.

I can, of course, switch the default path to just `usr/project` but it won't have `library2` selected as the default selection (or I don't see how).

In short, how can I have the `showOpenDialogSync` show the path to the parent folder of the default selection, with the default selection selected instead of opening the full path of that default selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality provided in the [Electron dialog API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogsyncbrowserwindow-options).

If there is a good case for your Electron app to have this feature, you may consider building the open dialog yourself. Of course, everything that the prebuilt dialogs give you is now yours to re-implement. Be aware that non-standard dialogs will throw off some users. Furthermore, should you also need a save dialog, you may end up re-implementing that as well for sake of uniformity.

---

Why doesn't Electron offer this option? Electron makes use of the file dialogs provided by the underlying operating system. That's why they look "native" in each operating system. It only passes through calls; its functionality cannot exceed that of the underlying dialogs.

It's possible that the file dialog of a specific OS is actually able to do what you want. Regarding Windows, [the docs suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog) that there is no way to select an existing item. For GTK, on the other hand, there is [`gtk_file_chooser_set_filename()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-filename), which (at least for save dialogs) allows to select an item. However, Electron's GTK save dialog implementation makes use of [`gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-current-name), which only allows to set a filename.

Whatever the functionality of the dialogs of a given OS may be, Electron would need to support those options in order for you to have a chance of using them.

Cross-platform frameworks like Electron offer a common abstraction of OS features like dialogs, so that developers building apps with Electron don't have to deal with the OS specifics for each OS that needs to be supported. On the flipside, that can also mean that only a *common subset* of functionality is available.

Comment: "On the flipside, that can also mean that only a common subset of functionality is available" <-- Philosophically makes sense, but there are some functions that surface in Electron that are OS only, or Windows only... so depending on the demand, it seems there are options to surface some niche requirements.

Comment: @Trees4theForest True!